# Javascript undefined error in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0, file-upload

I have used a dynamic FileUpload control.I have also applied two validations,first, to check if no file is uploaded and second,to check whether the size of the file being uploaded is greater than 10 mb.The code works fine in all browsers except in IE.In IE it throws error.

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Code I have implemented:

```
fieldValid = document.getElementById(AllfldID1[x]);
if (fieldValid.files.length != 0) { //to check if file uploaded or not
    var iSize = (fieldValid.files[0].size / 1024);
    iSize = (Math.round((iSize / 1024) * 100) / 100);  //Size in MB
    if (iSize > 10) {
        alert("Maximum File Size Limit is 10 MB for Field " + AllfldName1[x]);
    }
}
```

In other browsers(Firefox) if no file is uploaded then length is returned as '0' but in IE this does not work.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

In Internet Explorer in the developer console type

```
document.getElementById(AllfldID1[x])
```

And then you will be able to see all the properties related to this object.
Firefox, Chrome, IE have different naming convention for different properties. Once you type this in IE developer console you will see object and related properties for the same object.

Problem which I can assume is that

```
fieldValid.files
```

If not returnign all files because fieldValid having no property files in IE.

Comment: Yes there is no files property for fieldValid in IE.Then how can I check or if you can tell me which other property can i use to check if any file uploaded or not.And if uploaded then what is the file size?

Comment: In the object in the console you can find all the properties which the DOM element is having in IE. From there you can get your required property.